# Ошибка: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.x

При исполнении программа выдаёт ошибку:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/divinitytoffee/PycharmProjects/Vista/data.py /home/divinitytoffee/PycharmProjects/Vista/data.py:52: Warning: 
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '                                 '  cursor.execute(sql_client_id)"
```

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='divtof', passwd='31415', db='b15', charset='utf8')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor1 = db.cursor()
sql_client_id = 'SELECT id FROM Client WHERE SNILS = ' + SNILS + ';'
cursor.execute(sql_client_id)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Как это можно, собственно, исправить?

Comment: Использовать встроенную в MySQLdb подстановку значений в SQL-запрос вместо тупых и небезопасных плюсов

Comment: *Как это можно, собственно, исправить?* Для начала я бы предложил наказать того [censored], кто придумал использовать DOUBLE для хранения СНИЛС, и соответственно сменить тип данных. Затем - посмотреть, что же на самом деле получилось в переменной sql_client_id.

Comment: @Akina в базе он хранится в char

Comment: @andreymal а можно пример?

Comment: `cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM Client WHERE SNILS = %s', (SNILS,))`